# sqlite3 command does not save database after creation?

Tags: sqlite

I'm migrating from MySQL. I'm having trouble scripting a SQLite database creation. Similar code worked well for MySQL.

It appears the database and tables are created, but then `sqlite3` command does not save changes to disk.

```
$ sqlite3 < testdb.sql
$ ls -Al testdb.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 jwalton jwalton 0 Mar 25 04:02 testdb.db
```

And:

```
$ cat testdb.sql

ATTACH DATABASE 'testdb.db' AS 'testdb';
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

-- #####################################################

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name_number
(
        nn_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        nn_name VARCHAR,
        nn_number VARCHAR
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS number_index ON name_number(nn_number);

-- #####################################################

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS whitelist
(
        list_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        nn_id INT NOT NULL,
        list_date DATETIME,
        fk1_id INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY(fk1_id) REFERENCES name_number(nn_id)
);

-- #####################################################

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blacklist
(
        list_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        nn_id INT NOT NULL,
        list_date DATETIME,
        fk2_id INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY(fk2_id) REFERENCES name_number(nn_id)
);

-- #####################################################

INSERT INTO name_number (nn_name, nn_number) VALUES ("Test User", "4105551212");
INSERT INTO whitelist (nn_id, list_date) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), datetime('now'));

INSERT INTO name_number (nn_name, nn_number) VALUES ("Test User", "8005551212");
INSERT INTO blacklist (nn_id, list_date) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), datetime('now'));
```

How do I tell `sqlite3` command to save the database after creation?

Answer (score 1):

There are two databases here: the main database, which does not have a file name, and therefore is a temporary in-memory database, and the database named `testdb` with the file name `testdb.db`, which gets attached to the main database.

The SQL script does not mention `testdb` anywhere except in the ATTACH command, so all tables are created in the main database.

You shold drop the ATTACH command, and create the database file directly:

```
$ sqlite3 testdb.db < testdb.sql
```

Alternatively, replace the ATTACH with `.open testdb.db` to make that the main database. (The `.open` is not an SQL command and must not be terminated with a semicolon.)

The third option is to drop the ATTACH and to save the main database into the specified file using `.backup testdb.db` afterwards, but that only works in the command line interface, or by explicitly calling the [backup API](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html).

Comment: Thanks CL. Does SQLite have a `use testdb;`? The real script is a bit more involved and it would be easier to tell SQLite once rather than change the code throughout the SQL.

Comment: I gotta say, I don't know how you database guys tolerate the useless error messages produced by databases like MySQL and SQLite. It seems to be some sort of perverted [race to the bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_to_the_bottom) to see who can produce the most useless message.